# .htaccess not working with SSL config

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

I followed this guide to get a free SSL certificate from StartSSL: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-with-a-free-signed-ssl-certificate-on-a-vps

I followed it step by step but I don't actually understand it fully as I'm a newbie.

I have .htaccess which stopped working after I put the below code into my 000-default.conf file:

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on                                                                
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2                                                      
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM                
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.crt                           
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private.key                        
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/sub.class1.server.ca.pem 
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

This is what's in my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ $1.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404error
</IfModule>
```

^ It's basically to be able to access a page like this domain/page rather than like this: domain/page.php

So as soon as I add the above code from the 000-default.conf file, the rewrite rule works fine. If I add it in, however, I can no longer access files without the .php at the end. My 404 redirect is also not working.

What is it that's causing the problem?